# Comet-like behaviour with Python-Django

Tags: python, django, websocket, comet

My possibilities are limited, as I do have a nice host but can just use the normal server plan. Which means, only a normal server on port 80.

I have tried to read up some on WebSockets and/or Comet, and they mostly seem to require a second server running on another port.

Is there a way to get a stable Comet-like behaviour that scales nicely. My solution up to now is a script that sends a `GET` request every 5 seconds, which is not a good way to make a web chat. And I am afraid it might kill my server when a few dozen people are online.

So how can I get a reliable comet-like behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had some success using socket.io for asynchronous web stuff (comet). For Django in particular, I don't have any personal experience, but I found a nice article about combining [Gevent, Socket.io, and Django](http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/). Some other resources on Socket.io and Gevent can be found on my in a couple of my [blog](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2011/07/gevent-zeromq-websockets-and-flot-ftw.html) [articles](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2011/08/websockets-to-socketio.html) as well as a slideshare [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/rick446/realtime-web-gevent-and-socketio).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have huge trouble getting it to run.

Comment: It looks nice, but I get an error with xhr-polling, can you explain that somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking about the Django article, or the WSGI articles that I wrote? I don't have any experience with the Django one, but I have successfully run the code linked in the slideshare presentation (the chat server) multiple times. What error were you getting?